# Insert characters into a filename

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I have a directory with a bunch of files that are titled (for example)

```
how it is:            how it should be:
945TITLE-1.txt        945TITLE-00.txt
945TITLE-10.txt       945TITLE-01.txt
945TITLE-2.txt        945TITLE-02.txt
945TITLE-23.txt       945TITLE-03.txt
945TITLE-3.txt        945TITLE-10.txt
945TITLE.txt          945TITLE-23.txt
```

The numbers and the text which proceed the dash character can change so it needs to be variable.
Ignoring the file which is unnumbered (945TITLE.txt in this instance)
I'm using the following line to grab all the files which end in a dash and a single digit

```
file=`ls -1 working/pages/files | grep [-][0-9].txt`
```

But now I cannot figure out how to splice in the 0 between the dash and the digit.

```
for file in $filelist
do  
????
done
```

After several attempts I got furthest with this:

```
for file in working/pages/files/$filelist
do  
f1=${filelist%%[-]*}
f2=${filelist##*[-]}
finalName=${f1}-0${f2}
echo $finalName
mv $file working/pages/files/$finalName
done
```

The output for `$finalName` is `945TITLE-03.txt` every time and it only applies the `mv` command to `945TITLE-1.txt` (incorrectly changing it to `945TITLE-03.txt`) and  saying that it cannot find the other files (since it only looked the `working/pages/files/` folder for the first file)

Any help would be much appreciated and I am in no means married to this solution so if you can think of a more elegant one however different from what I'm proposing, I would be more than happy to hear it. Thank you

Comment: What is not clear is the folder structure: are all files in one folder or in separate folders?

Comment: Did you mean to have `file` instead of `filelist` when setting `f1` and `f2`?

Comment: Yes the xhtml should have been txt for this example.
$filelist is a list of all the files in the directory $file should be an element from that list

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example I made here, based on what you started with.  There is some funny special casing to handle your `945TITLE.txt` case:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in 945*
do
    suffix=${file##*[.]}
    base=$(basename ${file} .${suffix})
    prefix=${base%%[-]*}
    number=${base##*[-]}
    case ${number} in
        ''|*[!0-9]*) number=0 ;;
    esac
    echo ${prefix}-$(printf "%02d" ${number}).${suffix}
done
```

Comment: The problem is, I wont know what the files will be named. So maybe?
     for file in working/pages/files/*.txt

Comment: @ironintention, that will work fine too.  I just wanted to give a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

Idea :

1. Process line by line  ( example 945TITLE-1.txt)
2. First split by "-"  ( which gives "945TITLE" & "1.txt" , )
3. Then split second output of first split by "." ( which gives "1" & "txt" )

   ```
   ls -1 | awk '{ 
            n=split($0, array , "-");
            if( n > 1 ) {
              printf("%s-",array[1]);
              split(array[2],arraydot,".");
              printf("%02d.%s\n", arraydot[1], arraydot[2]);
             } else {
              split(array[1],arraydot, "."); 
              printf("%s-00.%s\n",arraydot[1],arraydot[2]);
            }
         }' | sort
   ```

   Else condition above handles the case for `945TITLE.txt`

Answer (score 0):

this awk-onliner will work: (you can first remove the ending `|sh` to check the generated mv commands.)

```
ls -[your options] |awk  -F'-|\\.' 'NF<3{x=$0;sub(/\./,"-00.",x)}NF>2{x=sprintf ("%s-%02d.%s",$1,$2,$3)}{print "mv "$0" "x}' |sh
```

I simulate it with a text file.

```
kent$  cat test.txt
945TITLE-1.txt
945TITLE-10.txt
945TITLE-2.txt
945TITLE-23.txt
945TITLE-3.txt
945TITLE.txt

kent$  awk  -F'-|\\.' 'NF<3{x=$0;sub(/\./,"-00.",x)}NF>2{x=sprintf ("%s-%02d.%s",$1,$2,$3)}{print "mv "$0" "x}' test.txt
mv 945TITLE-1.txt 945TITLE-01.txt
mv 945TITLE-10.txt 945TITLE-10.txt
mv 945TITLE-2.txt 945TITLE-02.txt
mv 945TITLE-23.txt 945TITLE-23.txt
mv 945TITLE-3.txt 945TITLE-03.txt
mv 945TITLE.txt 945TITLE-00.txt
```

if you pipe the result to sh, like `awk.....|sh` those mv command would be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Perl example that could work for you:

```
perl -E 'while(<*.txt>){ $a = $_; s/-\K\d\./0$&/ || s/\D\K\./-00./; rename $a, $_; }'
```

Not tested tho. ;-)